# xcdatamodel history causing git push errors

Tags: iphone, git, xcode4, push, xcdatamodel

I have enabled history for xcdatamodel file.From the xcode it appears to be one file 
from terminal its a set of folders

my.xcdatamodeld/

```
      my 2.xcdatamodel
      my.xcdatamodel
```

I am unable to deliver this to my remote git repository due to this error

```
 indmacsunelama$ git push
 Counting objects: 19, done.
 Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 34.11 KiB, done.
 Total 14 (delta 5), reused 7 (delta 1)
 remote: usage: git cat-file (-t|-s|-e|-p|<type>|--textconv) <object>
 remote:    or: git cat-file (--batch|--batch-check) < <list_of_objects>
 remote: <type> can be one of: blob, tree, commit, tag
 remote:     -t show object type
 remote:     -s show object size
 remote:     -e exit with zero when there's no error
 remote:     -p                    pretty-print object's content
 remote:     --textconv            for blob objects, run textconv on object's content
 remote:     --batch               show info and content of object standard input
 remote:     --batch-check         show info about objects fed from the standard input

 remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
 To git://mylinuxbox.us.spec.com/mobile.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git://mylinuxbox.us.spec.com/mobile.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Those errors indicate that you have a buggy hook installed in your remote repository.  Check the `hooks` subdirectory in `mobile.git` on your remote server and look at the hooks that are enabled.  It seems that the hook is misusing `git cat-file` at some point.

Comment: It seems like the space in the file name causes the git cat-file command in the hook to fail...Thanks Mark :)